# Tiles inside a html windows store app

Tags: html, css, windows

I want to port a web app (sorry, german, but you will unterstand what I mean: http://www.jalfm.de/games/Nerdquiz) to Windows store. If you go on the web page, you will see 4 different tiles at the beginning. I'd like to create something like that in my app. I looked through the whole list of controls (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465453.aspx#t_section), but I didn't find anything what was named "tile" or similar.
I know I could use the same CSS-class (Metro bootstrap) I used for the web app, but I'd like to know if there is a way to do that natively.

Comment: I think you should have looked some more.. The website is full of examples and information on what you're asking; All the subtitles of the section [Defining layouts and navigation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh767282.aspx) are useful for what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure if you unterstood what I want. I want tiles in the app, not on the start Screen. Can you please give me an specific link?

Comment: Well, in the link I passed you, the second option [Laying out an app page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh872191.aspx) ... I never did Windows HTML programming but it seems fairly simple. `One unit equals 20 × 20 pixels. Each unit is further divided into sub-units of 5 × 5 pixels` so, given that `writing HTML for a Windows Store app using JavaScript is a lot like writing HTML for Internet Explorer 10 running in standards mode. ` , you can use regular html-css to give your stuff properties... like `.tile { width: 100px; height: 100px; float: left;}` etc.

Comment: OK, thanks. I wanted to know if WinJS already Comes with a class like that, but I think I'm goint to create on myself.